# C# regex to match a string which has a delimiter

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, csv

I want to get the string which has a delimiter in it, between two specific words, using a regex.

e.g. I need a regex which matches:

> Statements1  start Statements2 ; Statements3 end fun;

There can be multiple occurrences of ' `;` ' between 'start' and 'end'.

Statements are multiple words where (.*) can be used in the regex for a word.

But the regex should not match if there is no ' `;` ' between the 'start' and 'end'.

Also, the 'end' should be the first 'end' encountered after 'start'

So, the regex should not match

> Statements1   start Statements2 end Statements3 ; end fun

I want the matches as

1. statements before 'start'
2. keyword
3. statements after 'start'

So, in this case it would be a group(for the 1st string since 2nd should not match) as:

1. Statements1
2. start
3. Statements2 ; Statements3 end fun;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the below regex will match your positive case and fail the negative case and place the results into group 1, 2, & 3.

`(.*?) (start) ((?:(?:.*?) ;)+ (?:.*?) end fun)`

In case you're unfamiliar with the (?:) syntax - they signify non-capturing parentheses.
Check out [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596002893/), it's a great reference for this topic!

Comment: yes, i'm familier with the ?: syntax. But i'm sorry to say that this regex is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
start ((Statements) ;)+ (Statements) end fun
```

Comment: This doesn't meet the capturing requirements

Comment: A pain when that happens isn't it!

Answer (score 0):

Might be quicker to use

```
    string[] Strings = stringToSplit.Split(new char[] { ';' });
    if (Strings.Count() > 1)
    {
        // Do your stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is as simple as:

```
(.*)(start)(.*;.*end.*)
```

This would return the groups you list.

Comment: You need non-greedy qualifiers on your *'s, or it will match the last "end", not the first.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, although substituting lazy *s causes it to group the final "fun;" with the next match.  Not sure how much this matters.